# Join dataframes by substring

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have 2 Pyspark dataframes with only 1 column:

```
df1 = [A234568ABC,
       A345636XYZ]

df2 = [B2345ABC890,
       B3412XYZ456]
```

I have to join these 2 dataframes by `substr` values by positions - df1 -> (8-10) and df2 -> (6-8)
How can I achieve this in PySpark.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try with `substring` function in join.

**`Example:`**

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
df1 = spark.createDataFrame([('A234568ABC',),('A345636XYZ',)],['id'])
df2= spark.createDataFrame([('B2345ABC890',),('B3412XYZ456',)],['id'])
df1.join(df2, substring(df1.id,8,2) == substring(df2.id,6,2)).show()
#+----------+-----------+
#|        id|         id|
#+----------+-----------+
#|A234568ABC|B2345ABC890|
#|A345636XYZ|B3412XYZ456|
#+----------+-----------+
```